# Min / Max Chars

Tags: actionscript-3

I've noticed that AS3 doesn't seem to contain a way of defining a minimum amount of characters required but does have a maximum.

Any way to do this with a textfield?

Comment: wouldn't a simple if/else condition suffice?

Comment: What would I be asking if though?

Comment: the minimum amount of characters for an input text field is 0.  there is no `minChars` property because such a property is hardly useful.  please edit your question to tell us what it is exactly that you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[joncys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009933/joncys) is pretty dead on - your TextField can't really have a minimum character limit other than 0, but you can give the user an error message if they try to submit information with too few characters.

Your TextField should have a string variable with its contents. Just check that the string's length is greater than or equal to your desired minimum, with an else clause that gives the user an error and doesn't let them submit/progress.

```
if (string.length >= 5) {
    // do whatever. They've entered at least 5 characters
} else {
    // Throw an error at the user.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The maximum characters per `TextField` is a hard constrain put on the `TextField` as a UI element itself, not the UI logic governing it. The minimum characters can in no way be tied to a UI component in such a fashion, because one could not enter the minimum characters, unless the minimum number would be a zero, which defeats the purpose of such constrain.

The cap is done more to maintain the integrity of your UI, not to constrain the input, since you want to do those checks in your programming logic.